# surface pro 2 text notification sounds for specific people

Tags: android-notifications

I have a MS Surface Pro 2 with Android 11. I setup a noticication sound for a person.
It works when the person texts me.
If I delete the text after receiving it, then notification sound is gone. As long as I keep 1 of the texts, the sound stays.
How can I assign a notification sound to specific people and keep it?